# Simple custom theme option not being saved

Tags: functions, theme-options, array

I'm not a web developer and have been following a tutorial on how to add options to a simple self-written theme.

In functions.php I've added the following code:

```
<?php
$themename = "Theme Name";
$shortname = "sn";
$options = array (


    array(  "name" => "Price"),

    array(  "type" => "open"),

    array(  "name" => "Price",
            "desc" => "Enter a price to sell your item for.",
            "id" => $shortname."_price",
            "std" => "",
            "type" => "text"),

    array(  "type" => "close"),

);
?>
```

In index.php I have the following code

```
    <?php if ($sn_price) { ?>
        <h2><? echo "$" . $sn_price; ?></h2>
    <? } else { ?>
        <h2>Price on registration of interest.</h2>
    <? } ?>
```

The theme options are available in the back end, and I have saved the price in the theme options.

The price is saved when I return to the back end to check the options, but $sn_price displays as empty on the front end.

Any ideas why?

**Edit**: Here is [functions.php](http://pastebin.com/Sw5QveND)

Comment: You need to show the code where/how the options are actually saved.

Answer (score 2):

Steve you're doing it wrong.

WordPress provides [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) that should be used for settings pages. If you aren't familiar with Settings API see great tutorial by Chip Bennett - [Incorporating the Settings API in WordPress Themes](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/02/17/incorporating-the-settings-api-in-wordpress-themes/).

Comment: I think the tute I was following applies to a Wordpress version older than 3 perhaps...

Comment: Settings API was introduced in WordPress 2.7, but I think most tutorials didn't used it back then.

Comment: Does register_setting() have to be declared after certain other functions?  I am getting the error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_setting() in /themes/themename/functions.php on line 73"

Comment: register_settings() should be called on admin_init, also check Twenty Eleven's theme-options.php file for more examples.